# Image processing: drawing a line though the axis of a bone

Tags: image-processing, axis

I hope someone can point me, to how I can solve my issue. . I have 6000 X-rays where I have to measure the angle between `bones`.

My strategy is the following: If I can somehow draw a `line1` though the long axis of `bone1`, and `line2` though the long axis of `bone2`, then I can simply measure the angle between the 2 lines.

So how can I find the axis in the first place? Is it possible to do it this way? :

(It is an x-ray picture) Lets say `1 cm` from the top of the picture, we scan that row for the first pixel that turns white (the first edge of the bone), here we have a dot `A1`, the we continue scanning until we find the first pixel that turns black (the second edge of bone ), this is dot `A2`, we draw a line between `Y1(A1,A2)`.

We do the same procedure, we go just further down lets say `10 cm` from the top, we then have another line `Y2(B1,B2)`. A line that goes from the middle of `Y1` to the middle of `Y2`, will be the axis of the bone
I already managed to play with the threshold, and making and edge. to make it easy to draw the lines ?

Does it make sense? 
Please, can it be done? Any idea how?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You need to provide a little more info for us to be able to help you, such as some representative examples of the pictures, what the measurements should be like etc

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

Maybe if you downsample the images to get less artifacts and/or apply some mathematical morphology (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology) to reduce the noise you can convert the bones into more line-shaped separated figures.

Apply some threshold so you can have black/white binary pictures. Use math to find a point in each of the 2 shapes and then try to match them to a rectangle or an oval. These will give you the axis you are looking for and then you can measure the angle.

Answer (score 0):

This is too general a question. Images would always be appreciated! I guess you have 6000 xrays producing a grayscale image of the bones. In this case the general idea would be to:
1. Find a good binary segmentation of the bones in 3d
2. Find a good [skeletonization](http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~palagyi/skel/skel.html) of the 2 bones, also look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/skeletonization/)
3. Replace the main skeletons of the two bones by line segments that best approximate it and measure the two angles (in 3d) between them
4. If this is two bones in the body - there is usually a limit to the degrees of freedom of two connected bones. It would be good to validate it wrt to this reference.

Tracing the line in realtime might not be the best in terms of accuracy. I guess this is obvious.

[This](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/59/02/12/PDF/3dpvt-skeleton.pdf) could give an idea for the full human pose.